# powershell regular expression - extract function names C source program

Tags: regex, powershell

I need to extract the names of functions defined in a C source file given as parameter to the script.
I'm not very familiar to PowerShell but shouldn't be something like this:

```
If ($FileExists -eq $True)
{
     select-string $args[0] -pattern "\(void\|double\|char\|int\) \.*(.*)"
}
```

Comment: I shouldn't have escaped the characters so-> `select-string $args[0] -pattern "(void|double|char|int) \.*(.*)"` works but how can I refer  the name of the function only (something like linux-sed would be useful)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd define the list of file extensions that you want to search in and use them in the Include parameter, then pipe to select-string and extract the capturing group matches.

```
dir -Path C:\c-program -Include *.h, *.c -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern '(void|double|char|int) (\w+)\(' | % {$_.Matches[0].Groups[2].Value}
```

Here's a canned example using function names from wikipedia:

```
'void incInt(int *y)','int main(int argc, char* args[])','int subtract(int x, int y)' | Select-String -Pattern '(void|double|char|int) (\w+)\(' | % {$_.Matches[0].Groups[2].Value}
```